# macOS set DNS server to default value

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm building a tool to manage DNS in macOS.

I know how to set dns server in terminal.

```
networksetup -setdnsservers Wi-Fi 1.1.1.1
```

but I don't to know how to unset it, or set it to the default value

```
networksetup -setdnsservers Wi-Fi
```

seems not working.

Anyone help ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give a try to:

```
networksetup -setdnsservers Wi-Fi empty
```

Then check with:

```
scutil --dns
```

From `man networksetup`:

```
-setdnsservers networkservice dns1 [dns2] [...]
...
If you want to clear all DNS entries for the specified network service,
type "empty" in place of the DNS server names.
```